# Pull and Release elastic effect uiviewcontroller?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, uipangesturerecognizer, pull-to-refresh

Hello everyone

I am trying to implement a pull and release effect like pull to refresh implemented in `UITableViewController` in a `UIViewController`.

I am trying to use `UIPanGestureRecognizer` or may be a `UIScrollview`. Any help?

[image]

Comment: `UIScrollView` already has this effect built-in.

Comment: could you tell us about the scenario with some more details.

Comment: please find edit i have uploaded a screenshot :)

Comment: You can create your view on UITableViewcell and add pull to refresh https://github.com/joshgrenon/PullToRefreshUIScrollView. On release reload tableview

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to show and hide the image, I think you can use the UITouch delegate methods effectively.

You can check the touch movement and its direction and show your image in:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
```

You can put your image back to default position in:

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
```

Hope this helps.